Recover key if 4 bits are flipped
import random
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad
from Crypto.Util.number import getPrime
import secret

size = 1024
x = getPrime(size)
p = 6

key = random.getrandbits(size)
while key >= x:
    key = random.getrandbits(size)

def encrypt(m, key):
    aes_key = hashlib.sha256(str(key).encode()).digest()
    cipher = AES.new(aes_key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    return cipher.encrypt(pad(m, 16))

y = pow(p, key, x)

ct = encrypt(secret.flag, key).hex()

for _ in range(4):
    flip = random.randint(1, size - 2)
    key ^= (1 << flip)

print(f"{x=}")
print(f"{y=}")
print(f"{ct=}")
print(f"{key=}")

I was trying to solve this challenge. The approach I arrived at was that since we are given key $k'$ which has atmost $4$ bits from $1-1022$ (following indexing of bits from $0$ with $0$ being LSB) flipped from the key $k$ we can test out each flip by utilizing $x$ and $y$. Flipping a bit is same as doing:
$6^{\pm2^i}*6^{k'} \pmod x$
where $i$ varies from $1$ to $1022$ depending on whether we flip $0$ to $1$ or vice-versa. The calculation should be relatively simple by repeated squaring (maybe we can even precompute it?). So we can then test out all combinations of 4 flips and compare the result to $y$ to see if we cracked the key.
In this approach I'm skeptical of the time complexity as 4 bits mean $O(n^4)$ time complexity which would be around $2^{44}$ iterations I believe. Is there a more efficient approach that I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Poncho's hint is the way to go. But I want to point out that the approach in the question would not require $2^{44}$ key tests. For a start flip can take $1022=2^{10}-2$ values, the 4 iterations in the CTF code can thus have $1022^4<2^{40}$ combinations of the 4 flip. Also the order of flips does not matter to the key generated, and equal flipcancel, so in the end there are $\binom{1022}4+\binom{1022}2+\binom{1022}0=45190252297<2^{35.4}$ possible keys. But Poncho's approach will find the right one after computing $<2^{20}$ list elements.

This is a CTF challenge, and so I won't give you the answer.
I will give you a hint: consider the giant-step-baby-step algorithm.  That is, what happens if you create two lists, one of which consists of all 2-bit differences in the exponent, that is:

The first list consists of $g^{key'} \bmod x$ for all $key'$ values that differ by at most two bits from $key$

The second list consists of $y \cdot g^{\pm 2^{i_1} \pm 2^{i_2}} \bmod x$ for all bit positions $i_1, i_2$ (where you include only $-i_1$ if the corresponding bit in $key$ is a 1 and only $i_1$ if the corresponding bit in $key$ is a 0, and similarly for $i_2$)?


How long will that take you?  What could you do with such lists?

That answer's $g$ is the question's p. In the second list we can restrict to $i_2>i_1$ and include $y$ which makes the list about twice smaller. In the first list, we can change "at most two bits" to "0 or 2 bits" to make the list slightly smaller and easier to compute. We need to store only one of the two lists.

@fgrieu: yeah, there are a bunch of obvious optimizations to the above procedure - I was hoping that infinite-blank would come up with them...

Thank I was able to solve it, btw it wasn't from an ongoing CTF so no worries on that front :)
